# Problems with max and min value of Chart.js [line chart]

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I want to create a small graph with just a line.
When I first created I didn't see a big different between the start point and the end point. So I tried to the set the smallest value the same as the min-val. And the biggest value as the max-val on my yAxes.

Here is my code:

```
var generateNormalChart = function (dataForNormalGraph, randomColors, theLongNameOfTheCoin,currency,exchange,minVal,maxVal,stepsize) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('normalChartGraph' + theLongNameOfTheCoin + currency + exchange).getContext('2d');
    var normalChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            borderColor: randomColors,
            data: dataForNormalGraph,
            pointRadius: 1,
            borderWidth: 2
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false

            }],
            yAxes:[{
                display: false,
                ticks: {
                    max: maxVal,
                    min: minVal
                    // stepSize: stepsize
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

};

An example of data I use:

This is the maxVal: 0.0000505

This is the minVal: 0.00005483

This is dataForNormalGraph:

```
0:0.00005162
1:0.00005124
2:0.0000505
3:0.00005056
4:0.00005089
5:0.0000509
6:0.00005102
7:0.00005067
8:0.00005087
9:0.00005156
10:0.00005173
11:0.00005191
12:0.00005363
13:0.00005276
14:0.00005309
15:0.00005297
16:0.00005231
17:0.00005243
18:0.00005252
19:0.00005271
20:0.00005326
21:0.00005408
22:0.00005483
23:0.00005376
24:0.00005365
```

Like you can see I commented the step value.
I even tried it with that by calculating the difference between `((the max and min val) / 25)` and that was : `1.7320000000000004e-7`

I also don't want to see the labels and the Axes value because it takes to much space.

I have 2 photo's like you can see he ignores the max and min val:

[image: A photo with the values on the yAxes]

What I want but then with the right max and min values

[image: what I want but then with the right max and min values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to give the yAxes values what didn't resulted in a good chart. 
The only thing I need to do was to add the

```
            labels: nameOfTheCoins,
```

so the yAxes have a value